EES/ETIAS in Schengen after 1-day overstay?
USA here,
3 years ago (2021) I accidentally overstayed the Schengen area by 1 day (91/180) because I had a suddenly cancelled flight (Origin Gran Canaria Spain), bought a ticket for the next available one (Layover in Portugal) but couldn't enter the passport gate until right before the new flight. I was stamped out without any obvious fanfare or restrictions, even if I, in a panic, did disclose what had happened after realizing what happened. The border guard simply smiled and said "that's alright, but never do it again, you can come back next year" and I was given no obvious ban or fine.
The next few years I was still being allowed in each time, one border guard only taking a pause for a second one time when looking through my passport (maybe calculating days?) but never said anything so I can only assume it WAS flagged in the SIS/VIS but was overlooked because of previous travel history or something..?
I travel to Europe to see family yearly and on subsequent visits, I left way more time on each so that if something like that were to ever happen again, I'd be well prepared and would never even have the CHANCE to overstay and break the law. I always have insurance and exit tickets booked at the same time as entry, and carry existing records with me when traveling.
That said, I'm worried about the EES/ETIAS systems being implemented because I'm well aware that any flag in the system can definitely mean that my applications and entry could easily be revoked/rejected in a similar fashion to the USA'S ESTA. I'm terribly sad that I made such a dumb and uneducated mistake and I've done a lot to ensure that it never happens again. I've seen many others do the same thing accidentally for a day or so, just about as unaware as I once was, and I'm wondering for their sake as well. Will travel simply be revoked for that many individuals?
Error or not, this does imply that I would be automatically excluded from getting the ETIAS, does it not? I'm also aware that the UK's ETA already has a digitized system for such things but I'm not exactly sure what their process is or how such things are handled for previous records prior to it's implementation.
Yes, I am fully aware that I did something stupid. I've tried asking elsewhere for opinions and advice but often get called "entitled" and "stupid" or mocked for my nationality if I even so much as mention it. I'm not here to break the law or skimp the rules or find any specific way to do so. I am however aware of a bilateral agreement that involves Spain, Portugal, the USA, etc and extended the 90/180 days, but I'm not interested in attempting to bring that up to argue my case, as rules are indeed rules.
Anyone have any help/opinions?
Thanks so much for reading.

By the time ETIAS actually comes into effect it's quite unlikely anybody will remember anything about your previous 1-day overstay. And IMHO it's very unlikely anything has been recorded in the VIS (because you don't actually need or use a visa) or SIS (because you haven't been banned).

@jcaron here I go again with mistaking VIS for EUROPOL again. Oops. Not sure if posts can be edited. I'm new here.

@jcaron Even so, assume "Have you ever overstayed a visa/overstayed the alloted time allowed to you by Schengen/any member states" would likely be a question, would it not? Answering "Yes" to that in the US is an automatic ESTA denial and bars from future applications.

You can edit questions with the "Edit" button below your question. But it's even less likely you would be flagged in the Europol databases for this.

By the time ETIAS finally comes into service (probably not before 2026 given the delay on the implementation of the EES) things may change, but at the moment the only relevant question is whether "you have recently been the subject of a return decision". The rest should come from EES, which will be a blank slate and the SIS, which shouldn't have any information about your overstay. And if ever it did now, it would be forgotten by then.

"assume "Have you ever overstayed a visa/overstayed the alloted time allowed to you by Schengen/any member states" would likely be a question, would it not?": that assumption is incorrect; see https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/AUTO/?uri=CELEX:02018R1240-20210803

phoog's link doesn't bring you directly to the right place in the legislation, but the questions are listed in Article 17(4). In short: Terrorist? Criminal? Visited a war/conflict zone? Deported? And note that even then, there's a manual review.

@jcaron thank you so much for the manual review reminder, as well + for the reminder of law :) I'll give this a read ASAP. The answer to the above questions are, in fact, no, no, no, and no! ;)

@jcaron is it possible to link to a specific place in the legislation?  I've never figured out how.  I suppose the absence of a "have you overstayed" question is because the real criterion is not whether you've overstayed but whether you have an active SIS alert -- and they know that because ETIAS is linked to SIS.

@phoog Was about to write that I couldn't find a way but I just found it (though you can only link an article, not subsections): click on the icon for the HTML version of the act in the language you want, then click on the requested chapter in the table of contents. To link to a later article in the chapter, right click on the "Article XX", select "Inspect Element", look for the id="tocIdXX" attribute, and replace the #tocIdXX at the end of the URL by the one you found. So Article 17 is https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:02018R1240-20210803#tocId23

@phoog It's less practical than the standard text version though as you don't have the navigation between the original text, consolidated versions, etc.

@jcaron As stated in phoog's sub, Update now that a phased rollout has been proposed - upon the application of these new programs, what should I do? There's still the stamp proving the overstay regardless. There is no obvious mandate (to my or your knowledge) and all applications must be approved by a human if flagged... so is this a sort of "wait and see" situation? :)


I can only assume it WAS flagged in the SIS/VIS but was overlooked because of previous travel history or something..?

Unlikely.  You won't be in VIS because you don't have a visa, and SIS as far as I know would only have a record if you'd been banned for any length of time.  The border guard who stamped you out after your 91 day stay would not have said "that's alright" if you'd been banned; instead, you'd have gotten a document describing the duration of the ban and the reasons for it.
Also, if you'd been flagged, you could expect every border guard to scrutinize all of your stamps every time, not "one border guard only taking a pause for a second one time when looking through my passport."
Finally, are you sure it was really 91 days?  People often miscount.  My mother miscounted this past summer because she counted from the day she left the US rather than from the day she arrived in the Schengen area.

I'm worried about the EES/ETIAS systems being implemented because I'm well aware that any flag in the system can definitely mean that my applications and entry could easily be revoked/rejected in a similar fashion to the USA'S ESTA.

The next time you enter after EES goes into effect, if you enter during the first six months, the border guard is supposed to check your passport stamps to see whether you have less than 90 days available.  If I recall correctly, there's no mandate to go back in time and enter visits to the Schengen area earlier than 180 days before your first entry.  There's certainly no mandate to create a ban where none exists.  And there isn't already an electronic database recording entries and exits, because that's what the EES is for, and it's not yet operating.
Accordingly, there is very little chance that any ETIAS would be refused once ETIAS goes into operation (which will be at least several months after EES does).

Error or not, this does imply that I would be automatically excluded from getting the ETIAS, does it not

No.  You would be excluded from getting ETIAS if you had a (current) alert in SIS to prevent you from entering the Schengen area.  This alert has to be entered by one of the Schengen member states -- it's not automatic.  Since you've visited several times since the overstay, you can safely conclude that there is no such alert.  Even if you have a current alert, the exclusion is not automatic but must be confirmed by a person.  (See https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/AUTO/?uri=CELEX:02018R1240-20210803 for the details.)
Anyway, an overstay due to a cancelled flight probably counts as "force majeure," for which your violation would likely be excused, though I believe that depends on the national law of the country through which you are leaving the Schengen area when the overstay is detected.  For an overstay in 2021 -- or any past overstay that was not addressed at the time -- there is really nothing to worry about.

Hello there! Thank you for your response. :)

Also thanks for the link, not many people do that!! And it means a lot. I actually did attempt to get my SIS data once I was made aware that retrieving it IS apparently a right, but never recieved a response, whether by mail or email. Some people say that it implies that there simply IS NO SIS data available/no flag. + also yes, I'm 100% sure it was 91 days. I recounted from the date of entry to the date of exit. I wasn't actually aware that 1 day was counted from the moment of entry until after it was too late and that was an oversight on my part entirely.

Update now that a phased rollout has been proposed - upon the application of these new programs, what should I do? There's still the stamp proving the overstay regardless. There is no obvious mandate (to my or your knowledge) and all applications must be approved by a human if flagged... so is this a sort of "wait and see" situation? :)

@cruxcrux "now that a phased rollout has been proposed": what phased rollout?  Do you mean that ETIAS will only be required at least six months after EES goes into operation?  That is not new; it was always planned to do it like that.  What should you do?  Stop worrying.  There's no basis to deny entry to the Schengen area for an overstay years earlier when the officer who noticed the overstay decided not to impose any punishment.

I saw an article a few days ago that the EES (not ETIAS) is to be introduced in a phased rollout (but it was only requested/to be requested and not approved of just yet, apparently some member states aren't quite ready still.) I knew about the ETIAS part. :) Thank you again. I'll do my best to worry less.

@cruxcrux I see, yes, I think I've seen the same or similar information about gradual introduction of EES, but I must have forgotten about that because it's been increasingly difficult to follow the repeated delays, so I've stopped trying.  I will remain skeptical that they'll meet any schedule they publish until after it's actually been put into service.

honestly, that's completely acceptable. it HAS been delayed for years now, hasn't it? it's basically a toss-up as to when it will actually come into play. i do find it interesting the other countries have seemingly met their promised dates so far, though! i see the UK has ETA just about ready to go.
